# How would I access a method from another script?

Tags: unity, c#

I have two scripts. I create a reference to my instance of `SoulManagement` from `Soul`, but I can not access it's method, and I can not figure out why. Why can't I access my method?

---

#### `SoulManagement`

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SoulManagement : MonoBehaviour 
{
    int Souls;

    void SoulPlusMinus(int SoulValue)
    {
        Souls += SoulValue;
    }
}
```

#### `Soul`

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Soul : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public SoulManagement soulmanager;
    public int SoulValue;

    void Start()
    {
        soulmanager = FindObjectOfType<SoulManagement> ();
    }
    void OnTriggerStay2D()
    {
        soulmanager.SoulPlusMinus (SoulValue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Making Methods Accessible

When we create methods, we often must explicitly state the *accessibility*. A `private` method can only be accessed from within the class<sup>1</sup>, while a `public` method can be accessed from *outside* of the class. If you do not specify the accessibility, this will default to `private`. If you later deal with *inheritancy*, it is worth noting that a `protected` method will remain *private*, while still allowing access to classes that derive from that class.

In this case, we have a method signature of `void SoulPlusMinus(int SoulValue)`. From the provided example, you *want* to use ***`public`***`void SoulPlusMinus(int SoulValue)`.

---

#### Easy Access for Management Classes

With a name like `SoulManagement`, we can infer that this class manages your `Soul` classes. Classes like this are often designed in a way that only *one* instance should be running. In other words, you would not have *many* soul managers; you would only have *one*.

If this description fits your intended functionality, creating a *singleton* pattern may provide additional benefit, and extend your access to the class methods. A singleton pattern helps assure that we retain the one instance of the class, and by creating a static self-reference, we can then make that class accessible from *anywhere*. You can read more on singleton patterns 
[over at Stack Overflow Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/unity3d/2137/singletons-in-unity).

---

This is your `SoulManagement` class as a singleton variation:

```
public class SoulManagement : MonoBehaviour 
{
    ///<summary>Self-reference should always point to our active instance.</summary>
    public static SoulManagement instance;

    void Awake()
    {
        // If we do not currently have a SoulManagement instance, 
        if(instance == null)
        {
            // This is our SoulManagement instance; link the instance reference.
            instance = this;
        } 
        else if(instance != this)
        {
            // If we DO have an instance reference, and it is NOT this instance,
            // We already have a SoulManagement class; destroy this instance.
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

    int Souls;

    public void SoulPlusMinus(int SoulValue)
    {
        Souls += SoulValue;
    }
}
```

Using this approach, you can simply call `SoulManagement.instance.SoulPlusMinus()` from *anywhere*, without having to set up a direct reference to the instance.

Comment: I just found this out myself. I feel so stupid.

Comment: @Insurikai, dont worry about it, have to learn somehow. This is not, by far, comparable to stupid mistakes I have made in the past.